# R: approximating `e = exp(1)` using `(1 + 1 / n) ^ n` gives absurd result when `n` is large

Tags: r, exponential

So, I was just playing around with manually calculating the value of `e` in R and I noticed something that was a bit disturbing to me.

The value of `e` using R's `exp()` command...

```
exp(1)
#[1] 2.718282
```

Now, I'll try to manually calculate it using `x = 10000`

```
x <- 10000
y <- (1 + (1 / x)) ^ x
y
#[1] 2.718146
```

Not quite but we'll try to get closer using `x = 100000`

```
x <- 100000
y <- (1 + (1 / x)) ^ x
y
#[1] 2.718268
```

Warmer but still a bit off...

```
x <- 1000000
y <- (1 + (1 / x)) ^ x
y
#[1] 2.71828
```

Now, let's try it with a huge one

```
x <- 5000000000000000
y <- (1 + (1 / x)) ^ x
y
#[1] 3.035035
```

Well, that's not right.  What's going on here?  Am I overflowing the data type and need to use a certain package instead?  If so, are there no warnings when you overflow a data type?

Comment: How so?  e is a horizontal asymptote of the function I'm inputting.  It should not approach 1.  It should approach e.

Comment: @self_learnt maybe [Why are these numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a problem with machine precision. As soon as `(1 / x) < 2.22e-16`, `1 + (1 / x)` is just 1. Mathematical limit breaks down in finite-precision numerical computations. Your final `x` in the question is already `5e+15`, very close to this brink. Try `x <- x * 10`, and your `y` would be `1`.

This is neither "overflow" nor "underflow" as there is no difficulty in representing a number as small as `1e-308`. It is the problem of the loss of significant digits during floating-point arithmetic. When you do `1 + (1 / x)`, the bigger `x` is, the fewer significant digits in the `(1 / x)` part can be preserved when you add it to 1, and eventually you lose that `(1 / x)` term altogether.

```
               ## valid 16 significant digits
1 + 1.23e-01 = 1.123000000000000|
1 + 1.23e-02 = 1.012300000000000|
   ...            ...
1 + 1.23e-15 = 1.000000000000001|
1 + 1.23e-16 = 1.000000000000000|
```

Any *numerical analysis* book would tell you the following.

- Avoid adding a large number and a small number. In floating-point addition `a + b = a * (1 + b / a)`, if `b / a < 2.22e-16`, there us `a + b = a`. This implies that when adding up a number of positive numbers, it is more stable to accumulate them from the smallest to the largest.
- Avoid subtracting one number from another of the same magnitude, or you may get [cancellation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). The web page has a classic example of using the quadratic formula.

You are also advised to have a read on [Approximation to constant "pi" does not get any better after 50 iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51693841/4891738), a question asked a few days after your question. Using a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) to approximate an irrational number is numerically stable as you won't get the absurd behavior seen in your question. But the finite number of valid significant digits imposes a different problem: numerical convergence, that is, you can only approximate the target value up to a certain number of significant digits. [MichaelChirico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51625092/4891738) using Taylor series would converge after 19 terms, since `1 / factorial(19)` is already numerically 0 when added to 1.

Multiplication / division between floating-point numbers don't cause problem on significant digits; they may cause "overflow" or "underflow". However, given the wide range of representable floating-point values (1e-308 ~ 1e+307), "overflow" and "underflow" should be rare. The real difficulty is with addition / subtraction where significant digits can be easily lost. See [Can I stably invert a Vandermonde matrix with many small values in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51662728/4891738) for an example on matrix computations. It is not impossible to get higher precision, but the work is probably more involved. For example, OP of the matrix example eventually used the [GMP (GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library)](https://gmplib.org/) and associated R packages to proceed: [How to put Rmpfr values into a function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51772954/4891738)

Answer (score 3):

You might also try the Taylor series approximation to `exp(1)`, namely

```
e^x = \sum_{k = 0}{\infty} x^k / k!
```

Thus we can approximate `e = e^1` by truncating this sum; in R:

```
sprintf('%.20f', exp(1))
# [1] "2.71828182845904509080"
sprintf('%.20f', sum(1/factorial(0:10)))
# [1] "2.71828180114638451315"
sprintf('%.20f', sum(1/factorial(0:100)))
# [1] "2.71828182845904509080"
```

Comment: @李哲源 yes, in fact `sprintf('%.70f', sum(1/factorial(0:17)))` is already numerically equivalent to `exp(1)` from R's perspective

Comment: so, better to write `sum(1/factorial(17:10))`? interesting!