# recursive dependence of data - for loop using rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I've got a function written in `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("NumericVector MatVecMul_cpp (NumericVector y, double k) {
  int n = y.size();
  NumericVector z(n);
  int i; double *p1, *p2, *end = &z[n];
  double tmp = 1.0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (p1 = &z[i], p2 = &y[0]; p1 < end; p1++, p2++) *p1 += tmp * (*p2);
  tmp *= k;
}
return z;
}")
```

Basically the goal of the function is to take a numeric vector and parameter `k` and to calculate output vector where an `i`-th element is a sum of `i-1`-th element multiplied by `k` and a `i`-th element of input vector `y`. However, now I need to make some tweak, i.e. I need to take additional parameter `c` which would tell that `c` row after non-zero value in `y` vector the output vector `z` should be 0. See desired output below with `c = 4`, `k = 0.9`.

```
structure(list(y = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 
0), z = c(0.7, 0.63, 0.567, 0.5103, 0.45927, 0, 0, 4, 3.6, 3.24, 
8.916, 8.0244, 7.22196, 6.499764)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

So once again, the `5`-th value of `z` is `0`, because the parameter `c` is equal to `4` so we doesn't multiply the previous value of `z` anymore. But the `11`-th value of `z` is `8.916000` as we don't only multiply previous value by `0.9`, but also add `6.0` from `y` column.

I have tried to create a new `0-1` column in `data.frame` named as `c` which would indicate if the `0.9` decrease is still considered or not and then tried to adjust above function, but the following didn't work (values of `z` doesn't reset where `c = 0`).

```
cppFunction("NumericVector adjust_cpp (NumericVector y, double k, NumericVector ctrl) {
          int n = y.size();
        NumericVector z(n);
        int i; double *p1, *p2, *p3, *end = &z[n];
        double tmp = 1.0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (p1 = &z[i], p2 = &y[0], p3 = &ctrl[0]; p1 < end; p1++, p2++, p3++) {
          *p1 += tmp * (*p2);
          *p1 *= *p3;
        }
        tmp *= k;
        }
        return z;
        }"
)
```

How can I accomplish that?

```
structure(list(y = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 
0), z = c(0.7, 0.63, 0.567, 0.5103, 0.45927, 0, 0, 4, 3.6, 3.24, 
8.916, 8.0244, 7.22196, 6.499764), ctrl = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("y", "z", "ctrl"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

With above data in *R* this would be:

```
fun <- function(y, k, ctrl) {
  n <- length(y)
  z <- numeric(n)
  z[1] <- y[1]
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    z[i + 1] <- (y[i + 1] + z[i] * k) * ctrl[i + 1]
  } return(z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Translating such a simple R function into Rcpp can be done line by line with minimal changes:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using Rcpp::NumericVector;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector funC(NumericVector y, double k, NumericVector ctrl) {
  R_xlen_t n = y.length();
  NumericVector z(n);
  z(0) = y(0);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    z(i + 1) = (y(i + 1) + z(i) * k) * ctrl(i + 1);
  }
  return z;
}

/*** R
df <- structure(list(y = c(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 
0), z = c(0.7, 0.63, 0.567, 0.5103, 0.45927, 0, 0, 4, 3.6, 3.24, 
8.916, 8.0244, 7.22196, 6.499764), ctrl = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("y", "z", "ctrl"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")

fun <- function(y, k, ctrl) {
  n <- length(y)
  z <- numeric(n)
  z[1] <- y[1]
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    z[i + 1] <- (y[i + 1] + z[i] * k) * ctrl[i + 1]
  } 
  return(z)
}

z <- fun(df$y, 0.9, df$ctrl)
all.equal(df$z, z)
z <- funC(df$y, 0.9, df$ctrl)
all.equal(df$z, z)
*/
```

For the provided vectors with length 14, the R version is still faster on this machine. Duplicating `y` and `ctrl` ten times gives vectors, for which Rcpp is already faster.